# How do I move objects around freely?

Tags: fallout-4

In previous Fallout titles, there has been a button you could press to "grab on" to items. This allowed you to freely move the item around, as if it was tethered to the cross hairs.

This can be used to drag corpses and other objects around, as opposed to the settlement mode, which allows you to move around items you own.

What is the button for this in Fallout 4? I am playing on PC.

Comment: Calling it the "physics button" makes for a confusing question title.

Comment: This seems to be an artifact due to changing to the Skyrim engine.  Fallout 3/NV had a dedicated button for moving items, ala Oblivion, but Skyrim had the "Use button also moved items when held", so that's now also in Fallout 4.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The drag item key is the same key (<kbd>E</kbd> on PC, <kbd>X</kbd> on PS4, <kbd>A</kbd> on Xbox One) used for picking up objects. You hold the key until it picks up the item, then you can let go while you're moving around. Press the key again to drop the item.

However, this is also the same key used to exit power armor. Suffice to say, it's somewhat less frustrating if you do your object manipulation while not wearing power armor.

Additionally, you can edit the items in Workshop mode with the same key. Making adjustments in workshop mode seems to subtly alter the object properties, turning the item into static/placed decorations rather than ground clutter.

For example, looted balls placed on a crafted pool table will move around if you walk on the table and bump into them. If you manipulate them in workshop mode, they become attached to the table like crafted decorative objects.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, Turbo. I don't play on consoles, so I wasn't 100% sure what the buttons were.

Answer (score 6):

Just press and hold the "use" key until the item can be dragged. That key is "e" on my keyboard layout. It is the same key used to select objects in workshop mode.

Answer (score 3):

Hold down the key bound to Activate while pointing at something. This is a toggle so once you've picked whatever it is up you can let go and press the button again to release.